# Most elegant way to check if a process is running, and start if not?

Tags: bash

I've been messing around with various ways to do this in bash, and I've found `pgrep program > /dev/null || program` to be the shortest/most elegant way of doing this.  Is there a better method than this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `pgrep`, you might match other programs than just yours. If you want to be sure to match the right program, use `pidof` instead.

You could also use `start-stop-daemon` with a PID file. `start-stop-daemon` will check if the program is running and start it if required. This is what is used in most init scripts.

Comment: Going through the man file of start-stop-daemon and it looks nice.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: You might also be interested in the `/lib/lsb/init-functions` library, which most init scripts parse to use wrapper functions such as `start_daemon` or `pidofproc`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ -z `pidof program` ] || echo "program runing"
# or 
[ -z `pidof program` ] && OtherProgram
```

Comment: Could you please explain to the OP what to do with this command?